# Ionic footer pushed above keyboard on user input

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

Everytime when keyboard is opened ionic footer is pushed directly above keyboard. Can I disable such footer behavior?

I am using Ionic 5 with capacitor.

Comment: just add css on footer

position:absolute;
bottom:0

Comment: It's not working. even if I add css to custom or global css.

Comment: Can you share code in stackbliss